# python subprocess module to call shell (Bash) script

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I am trying to call a shell (Bash) script from python. The script is in my /home/user/bin directory with execute permission for group & user, i.e., `-rwxr-xr--`. I am using `subprocess.check_call(["/home/user/bin/script.sh %s %s" % (subj,-6)],shell=True)` and this is generating an exit status 127 code. Adding `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` to the command does nothing to elucidate. Here is the exact output:

> CalledProcessError: Command
>   '['/home/.../bin/MNE_setup_source_space.sh kubi_td104 -6']' 
>   returned non-zero exit status 127`

I believe this might be a PATH related issue, is that correct? I don't know how to resolve this. If I am already passing in the absolute path to the executable how can there be a PATH issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `shell=True`. Do not pass arguments as part of `argv[0]`. Pass your argument vector as a vector -- which is to say, in Python, a list:

```
subprocess.check_call(["/home/user/bin/script.sh", str(subj), "-6"])
```

If you *were* going to use `shell=True`, you would do it like so:

```
subprocess.check_call("/home/user/bin/script.sh %s %s" % (subj,-6), shell=True)
```

...which is to say, you wouldn't use a list form at all.

---

To clarify why what you're currently trying is failing -- because you're using `shell=True`, it's trying to pass only the first list element as a script, and additional arguments as extra argv elements which would only be read or interpreted if the script passed in the first argument chose to look at them (as by referring to `"$1"`, `"$2"`, or the like).

`shell=True` is only needed in very rare circumstances where you need a shell to perform redirections or logic before starting the program you're trying to run, and comes with serious security concerns if any unvetted input is incorporated into the command being run. Do not use it unless you're very, very sure you need to.

Comment: `subprocess.check_call(["/home/user/bin/script.sh", subj, str(-6)])` where `subj` is already a workspace string variable generates an OS Exec format error [Errno 8]. Which I had encountered before stumbling onto the 127 exit code.

Comment: This however `subprocess.check_call("/home/kambiz/bin/MNE_setup_source_space.sh %s %s" % (subj,str(-6)), shell=True)` simply spits out `0`. What does that mean? I am not seeing the results of the script!

Comment: @Kambysese In your first comment, you aren't casting `subj` to a string (as the example does). You need to do that.

Comment: @Kambysese Your question doesn't say anything about where you want stdout and stderr from the script to go, so I don't know what "not seeing the results" means. If you used a command you were actually willing to show us, rather than an opaque `script.sh`, then we could reproduce your problems and/or demonstrate correct behavior -- nothing here is different when invoking shell scripts vs other commands.

Comment: @Kambysese ...by the way, to give an example of the kind of bug which will be created by `shell=True` here -- let's say your `subj` has more than one word in it. If, for instance, `subj = "Hello world"`, `"script.sh %s %s" % (subj -6)` will evaluate to `script.sh Hello world -6`, rather than `script.sh "Hello world" -6` as you want it to... and the results of `subj="$(rm -rf ~/)"` would be worse. Using `shell=False` prevents this entire class of bugs entirely, rather than just getting you deeper and deeper into fighting quoting and evaluation rules.

Comment: *"it's trying to treat the first argument as a string"* is wrong: `check_call()` doesn't call `str(["foo"])` (`[` and `]` are from  [the error message formatting](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/subprocess.py#l373)). `shell=True` can work with a list argument (it is equivalent to `['/bin/sh', '-c'] + args` in this case).

Comment: I think using subprocess module's subprocess.Popen() might be wiser option.

Comment: @user2921139, what do you mean? `subprocess` is a module, not a function or class; it isn't callable on its own.

Comment: Thank you CHarles Duffy for the correction. I just corrected it to what I meant.

Comment: @user2921139, ahh. That really depends on what you want -- if your goal is to throw an exception if your object doesn't return an exit status of 0 when run, and you don't need the extra control provided by a direct handle on the Popen object, then `check_call` is the right thing. I don't know that there's an argument to be made that it's generically poor practice, if one's use case matches its behavior.